# Slides conflitando entre si

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estou com o seguinte problema possuo um slide logo no inicio da minha página na tag `<header>` porem um dos seus códigos é importado essa seria a [url](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) porem agora na minha `<section>` possuo mais uma tag que é de um outro slide seria essa [aqui](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js) essa url está conlitando com a do meu `<header>` será que e possível consertar isso axiste uma outra maneira de ser feita lembrando que coloquei ambas as urls no navegador e copiei o código para um arquivo `.js` e salvei dentro do meu projeto porem mesmo assim ainda continuam conflitando

Esses dois slides são de um site segue a url dos dois slides que tenho que usar:

[slide do header](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/)
[slide da section](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os links que apontaste são:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
```

Parece-me que tens versões diferentes da mesma biblioteca (jQuery) a serem carregadas na página. Isso causa erros pois as variáveis sobrepõe-se e partes do código reinicia-se.

O melhor nesses casos de plugins que vêm com versöes locais de bibliotecas é manter a mais recente (`1.8.3` no teu caso). E por vezes pode ser altura de ir buscar uma versão ainda mais atual, tavez `1.11.3` no teu caso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente pelo que percebi você está fazendo uso de plugins para algum comportamento específico (slide / gallery...) em seu web site e os mesmo tem como dependência o **Framework jQuery**. Dicas:

1.Se for carrega-los de um (host/sever/cdn), quando estiver em **fase de desenvolvimento** alocar os links antes do fechamento da tag `<body>`, por questões de desempenho assim não haverá o bloqueio do carregamento do DOM.

2. Use apenas uma versão jQuery e a mais compatível, aquela que contempla **features do IE** por exemplo, assim você não precisa prever fallbacks pra coisas idiotas.

3. Verifique a documentação dos plugins que está usando pois as vezes só rodam com versões específicas do Framework

Eh seja feliz no modo mamãe js!